# Learning JSON in relation to php

Tags: php, json

Anyone knows where i can get good introduction info on json in relation to php

Answer (score 7):

You can check the PHP manual for [JSON functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php): [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

You can also take a look at [json.org](http://json.org/) for the JSON spec.

In brief, JSON is a data format that can be read natively by Javascript, which makes it very fast and convenient for doing AJAX requests or generally passing information from server-side scripts to Javascript.

Comment: It depends on the JavaScript implementation if it can be read natively.

Comment: I think its important to say that almost the languages now accept json; Is closer to become an official array structure cross-language ;)

Answer (score 0):

there's not much to be introduced to.  try `var_dump(json_encode($x));` and `var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($x)));`  for different values (and types) of `$x`, and you know basically everything there is to it.